# CMake configure_file with out of source build

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to use CMake to create some header files that will be read in by my source code. My problem is that when I run `cmake ..` in my `build/` folder, it generates the configuration file inside my build folder, and then when I run the generated Makefile it fails to find the header.

Of course I could fix this by using `#include "build/config.h"` from my C++ file rather than `#include "config.h"`, but it seems like my C++ code shouldn't know about my build folder (I might want more than one possible build setup, for example). Similarly, I could ask CMake to write the header file to the source directory, but that's breaking the out-of-source build setup.

Is there a way of getting CMake to generate a Makefile that will build, subject to these constraints?

My CMakeLists.txt is below. It reads in `config.h.in` and outputs `config.h`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(fftb)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(fftb_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set(fftb_VERSION_MINOR 0)

configure_file(
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/config.h.in"
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h"
)

add_executable(fftb main.cpp config.h.in)
```

My `config.h.in` is below, it #defines the version to be used in main.cpp

```
#ifndef FFTB_CONFIG_H_IN_H
#define FFTB_CONFIG_H_IN_H

#define fftb_VERSION_MAJOR @fftb_VERSION_MAJOR@
#define fftb_VERSION_MINOR @fftb_VERSION_MINOR@

#endif //FFTB_CONFIG_H_IN_H
```

My `main.cpp` is below, it includes the auto-generated `config.h` and outputs it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "config.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Version " << fftb_VERSION_MAJOR << "." << fftb_VERSION_MINOR << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if you wrote `add_executable(fftb main.cpp "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h")`?

Comment: Why you don't use include_directories to add the directory containing  the .h file ( in this case   PROJECT_BINARY_DIR)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add your build directory to the list of directories to search for include files by adding something like `include_directories(${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})` to your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Do not use `include_directories`. In *Modern CMake*, you want to use the `target_*` functions instead

Comment: This (or using cmake target_include_directories) is the correct solution.